# Selenium "can't kill an exited process"

Tags: java, selenium

Every time I ran my .jar, which is on the server. I was getting an error. When I run the application on Windows, everything works.

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: invalid argument: can't
>   kill an exited process
>       Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
>       System info: host: 'autoru', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.15.0-70-generic', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_222'
>       Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
>       remote stacktrace: 
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
>         at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>         at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
>         at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
>         at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
>         at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
>         at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
>         at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
>         at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>         at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:531)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:147)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
>         at com.company.bot.Test.Test.connect(Test.java:24)
>         at com.company.bot.bot.Parsing.ParsinTop.start(ParsinTop.java:44)
>         at com.company.bot.bot.Parsing.ParsinTop.run(ParsinTop.java:24)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Code

```
    public class Test {

    public String connect(String url) {
        DataBase dataBase = new DataBase();
        dataBase.connect();
        String result = "";
        try {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/usr/bin/geckodriver");
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            //url = url.replace("https://auto.ru/cars/", "https://auto.ru/moskva/cars/");
            driver.get(url);
            System.out.println("Connect to " + url);
            driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='button button_blue']")).get(0).click();
            System.out.println("After accept");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
                driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='CardPhone-module__phone OfferNewStickedBlock-module__contacts CardPhone-module__preview']")).get(0).click();
                System.out.println("Click contack");
            } catch (Exception e){
                driver.quit();
                connect(url);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            while(result.equals("") || result.equals(" ")) {
                Document document = Jsoup.parse(driver.getPageSource());
                Elements elements = document.getElementsByClass("CardGroupListingItem-module__footerCell_left");
                Element el = elements.get(0).getElementsByClass("Link CardDealerName-module__dealerName").get(0);
                result = el.attr("href");
            }

            driver.quit();
        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

After these errors, a lot of geckodriver starts. And

```
driver.quit();
```

doesn't kill geckodriver process. 
How can this be fixed?